# Sort HashMap basis on Object's member variable from value

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap

Have one class

```
class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

and one map which contains this object in value

```
Map<Integer, Employee> map = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
```

Now I want to sort above `map` one the basis of `Employee's name`. Means when I iterate this map using `Map.Entry`, `Employee` objects must retrive alphabetically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your samples which you have tried.

Comment: I didn't tried. I just search for this requirments, but didn't find any post for the same.

Comment: I think you can find your answer in this post : [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Comment: @Michaël, Thanks for your reply and it works for me. did some change in it. Posting changes in ANS. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michaël suggested one link which is [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) . I did some change in it. and it works for me

```
class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    Map<Integer, Employee> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<Integer, Employee> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return ((Employee)base.get(a)).compareTo(base.get(b));
    }

}

class Employee implements Comparable {
    public String name;
    public int id;

    Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        return this.name.compareTo(((Employee)obj).name);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

For solution please refere above mension link too.

Thanks for all who have reply.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) using this constructor:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)

Comment: This method is contractually for sorting based on keys, although it is possible.

Comment: @NilsH: Since it allows a custom comparator you can write your own logic to sort.

Comment: Yes, you can, but the point was that the contract is that it is sorted by keys.

Comment: @NilsH: As long as you get it done efficiently and by saving extra coding I guess it should be fine.

Comment: Sure, I'm not disagreeing on the solution :) I'm just pointing it out for the original poster to be aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort a `HashMap`, but you can sort its entries obtained with `entrySet()`.

```
public class MapSort {
    private static class Employee {
        public String name;

        public Employee(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
           return name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Employee> map = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();

        map.put(1, new MapSort.Employee("x"));
        map.put(2, new MapSort.Employee("a"));
        map.put(3, new MapSort.Employee("f"));

        List<Map.Entry<Integer, Employee>> entryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Employee>>(map.entrySet());

            Collections.sort(
                    entryList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Employee>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Employee> integerEmployeeEntry,
                                   Map.Entry<Integer, Employee> integerEmployeeEntry2) {
                    return integerEmployeeEntry.getValue().name
                            .compareTo(integerEmployeeEntry2.getValue().name);
                }
            }
        );

        System.out.println(entryList);
    }
}
```

After sorting you can put back your entries in a map that supports ordering, for example [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

It depends on your use case: if you need to keep the map always sorted it's simpler to employ a `TreeMap` that comes with an additional overhead. If you need just an one time sorting, you can use a `HashMap` with the above code.